# React Native FaceID Local Authentication

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to add local authentication with FaceID

I'm using expo [LocalAuthentication](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/local-authentication/)

In my device I have initialized faceID but it's not asking for faceID It's only asking device password

##### Here is my code

```
import useLocalAuthenticationTypes from '../../../hooks/useLocalAuthenticationTypes'

const result = await LocalAuthentication.authenticateAsync({
  promptMessage: 'Authenticating for Clock In',
  fallbackLabel: '',
})
```

I have try to allow faceID permission from iphone settings but I don't find the correct option